# C++ Extending Class Forcing some methods private

Tags: c++, extend

My question is simple: ~Given two classes, I want to one of them to extend the other one, but turning some methods to be `private`:

```
Class B
public Method a();
public Method b();
public Method c();

Class A extends B
private Method a();
private Method b();
public Method c();
```

Is this possible and how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Private Inheritance is for.

```
class A:   private B
{
    // All methods of class B are now private.
    // To make some "public" again:
    public:
        Method c()  { return B::c(); } // Call the private c-method from class B.
};
```

Comment: Can't you also use `public: using B::c;` to expose a method?

Comment: @FredLarson:  That also works  [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)

Answer (score 1):

Use private inheritance, all the function in base class B will become private.

```
  class A:   private B
  {
  }
```

Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance in C++ are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance).

Comment: Minor issues:  `class` is lowercase, not Pascal-case.   Classes end with a semi-colon (`;`).

Comment: @Piotr S. you are correct. But what is missing from the response is that now OP has control of what methods to expose if wished.

Comment: @MatiasFG OP has the same ability to control access with any other inheritance as well

Answer (score 0):

You could change the inheritance type from public to private, when you declare class B.

```
class B : public A {
   private:
      baseMethod();
};
or
class B : private A {
   public:
      baseMethod();
};
```

The use appropriate override that you want for each method.

Looks like you don't want all of the methods to turn private. Choose the type of inheritance based on the fraction of methods changing their visibility.